# Problems with sums of chars in C

Tags: c, encryption, char

I'm very new to C so I'll make it quick: I'm making a Caesar's Cipher but at some point it starts giving me ? symbols.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char c;
    int k;

    printf("Inserisci la chiave di cifratura: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    if (k > 26)
        k = (k%26);
    printf("%d", k);

    while ((c=getchar()) != '.') {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                c = c + k;
                if (c > 'z') {
                    c = c - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                }
            }
            else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                c = c + k;
                if (c > 'Z') {
                    c = c - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
        else
            putchar(c);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If k is 6, it starts giving me the symbol with z.
If it is 7, it start with y.
Etc...

I can't find anything around, thank you to whoever helps me.

Comment: FYI, you can use `islower()` and `isupper()` instead of writing your own tests.

Comment: read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `char`, it's implementation-defined whether it's treated as `signed char` or `unsigned char`. Your implementation apparently defaults to `signed char`. The value of `'z'` is `122`, and when you add `6` to this you get `128`, which overflows and causes undefined behavior. The maximum value of `signed char` is `127`.

You should declare `c` to be `int` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: @EkoLogiko Be aware that this is only one of several issues. At the very least consider what happens when `k` is 26. There might be more that neither Barmer nor I have spotted.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not sure Caesar cipher is defined when k is outside the range 1-25.

Comment: @Barmar Of course not. Yet the code explicitly handles k > 26.

Comment: Change `if (k > 26)` to `if (k >= 26)`

Comment: I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution ensures the offset k is in the range of 0 through 26. You can get the correct solution if your offset is in the range of 0 through 25. An offset of 26 should produce the same results as an offset of 0.

When calculating the offset character you simply add K and then try to use addition to adjust for values greater than 'z' or 'Z'. You can adjust the value without the use of another set of conditional statements using the modulus operator.

Since this appears to be a homework problem I have created a solution in Ada rather than C. You can translate the logic into C.

```
with Ada.Text_Io; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   subtype Offset is Natural range 0..25;
   K : Offset;
   C : Character := ' ';
   Code : Natural;
   adjusted : Character;
begin
   Put("Enter the letter shift amount: ");
   Get(K);
   Put_Line("Specified offset is" & K'Image);
   while C /= '.' loop
      Get(C);
      if C in 'a'..'z' then
         Code := (Character'Pos(C) - Character'Pos('a') + k) mod 26;
         adjusted := Character'Val(Code + Character'Pos('a'));
         Put(adjusted);
      elsif C in 'A'..'Z' then
         Code := (Character'Pos(C) - Character'Pos('A') + k) mod 26;
         adjusted := Character'Val(Code + Character'Pos('A'));
         Put(adjusted);
      else
         Put(C);
      end if;

   end loop;

end Main;
```

Ada does not allow arithmetic directly on characters. Instead it allows arithmetic on the "position" of the character, which is a numeric value. The function Character'Pos(C) returns the numeric position of the character stored in variable C. The function Character'Val() returns the character corresponding to a specified numeric value.